# Django forms: initial field value not working with @staticmethod vs unbound function

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm using Django 2.2 forms and I'm trying to understand why the below two snippets have different behaviors. Why does passing a @staticmethod to `initial` in the form field (snippet A) not have the same result as passing an unbound function (snippet B)?

Snippet A:

```
class BankUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    @staticmethod
    def yesterday():
        return date.today() - timedelta(days=1)    

    from_date =  forms.DateField(initial=yesterday)
    to_date =  forms.DateField(initial=date.today)
```

Snippet B:

```
def yesterday():
        return date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
class BankUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    from_date =  forms.DateField(initial=yesterday)
    to_date =  forms.DateField(initial=date.today)
```

Snippet B will work as intended and show the correct initial field value. Snippet A will only print the function's `str`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/659a73bc0a2df9be856e23fcfc6cc66d0d1a35fd/django/forms/forms.py#L482),

> ```
> def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
>     """
>     Return initial data for field on form. Use initial data from the form
>     or the field, in that order. Evaluate callable values.
>     """
>     value = self.initial.get(field_name, field.initial)
>     if callable(value):
>         value = value()
>     return value
> ```

Which indicates, the `yesterday` is not a callable method, but **`BankUpdateForm.yesterday`** is.

To execute `staticmethod`s, you should call it with their class as, **`BankUpdateForm.yesterday`**, which is not possible while defining the form fields.

So, You don't have to use **`@staticmethod`** decorator here,

```
# Method-1
class BankUpdateForm(forms.Form):

    def yesterday():
        return date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

    from_date = forms.DateField(initial=yesterday)
    to_date = forms.DateField(initial=date.today)

# Method-2 (You already have this)
def yesterday():
    return date.today() - timedelta(days=1)


class BankUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    from_date = forms.DateField(initial=yesterday)
    to_date = forms.DateField(initial=date.today)
```

Comment: staticmethods can be called using the object directly intead of class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod

Comment: Could you reference the exact answer you want to refer here? Unfortunately, I didn't see any example that calls a static method without using it's class

Comment: The first answer shows it. 
Btw my point is: objects can call staticmethods too.

Comment: Yes, ***objects can call `staticmethod`s too***, but not in this case since we have no objects here. @TâmerPinheiro

Answer (score 0):

because yestday is a `staticmethod`, so `callable(yestday)` return `False`, then just return the function
when getting the intial value for field. You can just drop `@staticmethod` decorator,it works well;
or pass `BankUpdateForm.yestday` to `initial`, it does too.
Note that staticmethod should be called by a class or instance, even if it's called in its class scope.